# Left to Right Alpha-Beta Pruning

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

Trying to understand (left-right) Alpha-Beta Pruning. A leaf can be "pruned" when the Alpha => Beta, and for each level the Alpha is the best value of the maximizer node and the beta is the best value of the minimizer node. So looking at the following, for a left-right Alpha Beta Pruning....

[image]

Am I correct in saying that node b is 3, it then goes back up the tree to a and all the way down to the i node where i has a alpha of 3 and a beta of -infitity , it chooses the m which is 0 and that becomes the new beta, and because 3=> 0 we can cut off the n node as not having to be explored?

Comment: The answer is Yes, but yes/no questions aren't on topic here.

Comment: Take it to [Computer Science] if you have more questions.

Comment: You may want to use a tool like https://movingai.com/ab/ to analyze alpha-beta's performance on different trees.

Comment: That seems like a great tool for balanced trees, I'm trying to follow how to do it with unbalanced trees.

Comment: @Jamie If you set all the leaf values to be the same in a subtree, it's the same as an unbalanced tree.

Answer (score 1):

So worked out would this be the answer with the red line marked through the nodes you dont have to visit?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The value of b (Min) is a derivative from the output of 3 as it is less than 5 --> d; then the value propogates up to node a as a is max, initially, value b is 3 and a will provision the value when moving to f a Min node, with i, j with 5 and 7 respectively since f is min node, its less then 1 of the values which is 5. f = 5. f > b, f = i as 0 < 5 of curr_beta. m = 0,0 < b(3), f(a=3), beta cutoff at f to maximize the parent of f(c), >= 3 value from left sub tree from b, so nothing less than 3 (f) of ms value(0), do not valuate node n as maximizer >= 3.